# Maintaining logs in redis cache using java

Tags: redis

**Requirement** - That our application processes files containing records and we have to maintain the log for the records in every file. The log file could easily be 100 MB at times in size.

**Solution** - Since database operation would be very heavy, so we wanted to go for in-memory cache. Write the logs for a particular file into a redis key (key might be the unique file name itself). Later when the user wants to see the log file, application should be able to read the contents from the cache using the unique key file name and write its content into a file which the user can see/download.

**Question** - Is this a good idea that, we keep appending the logs for a particular file to the same key and later when we have to write to the file, we read from the key and write the contents to the file? Basically the value of the redis key would always be string and its size might run into 100 MBs in size. Will there be any problems because of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve with redis easily, but don't forget that redis is in-memory store (make sure you don't run out of RAM). Ask yourself why you want to go for in-memory store over normal disk operations while dealing with files. If you feel like more frequent read operations happens and accessing time is crucial go ahead with redis.

Regarding size - 100MB is not a problem, in redis string can hold upto 512MB & List, Set, Hashes can hold >4billion records

I prefer MongoDB(which is a disk-based document store) for this kind of operations over redis.

Consider looking at [this link](http://highscalability.com/blog/2011/7/6/11-common-web-use-cases-solved-in-redis.html) to know when redis is awesome.